# Upload file to a remote server, how should I?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, file-upload

I am scratching my head about this. My scenario are that I need to upload a file to the company server machine(to a folder on c:) from our hosting one(totally different server). I don't know how I should do this. Any of you got tips or code on how this is done.

Thanks Guys

Comment: You need to run some kind of file transfer service on the destination server, then connect to it from the client (where the file is being moved from).  SFTP (Secure Shell FTP) is a good choice, though it's not supported out of the box.

Comment: Dejan - thanks for selecting my answer as "the answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set up an FTP server (like the one in IIS or a third-party server) on the Company Server.  If security is an issue then you'll want to set up SFTP (secure FTP) rather than vanilla FTP since FTP is not a natively secure transfer protocol.  Then create a service on the Hosting Server to pick up the file(s) as they come in and ship them to the company server using C#/.NET's FTP control.  Honestly, it should be pretty straightforward.

**Update:** Reading your question, I am under the strong impression that you will NOT have a web site running on the company server.  That is, you do *not* need a file upload control in your web app (or already know how to implement one given that the control is right in the web page toolbox).  Your question, as I understand it, is how to get a file from the web server over to the company server.

**Update 2:** Added a note about security.  Note that this is less of a concern if the servers are on the same subdomain and won't be routed outside of the company network and/or if the data is not sensitive.  I didn't think of this at first because I am working a project like this now but our data is not, in any way, sensitive.

Comment: You should at least mention that FTP is totally insecure.

Comment: Where as (FTP) is totally insecure, FTP can come in a variety of forms including SFTP which is also routinely referred to as FTP. Though I would not recommend FTP without more info, FTP may be a perfectly adequate method of dealing with this situation.

Comment: U got it right Mark. So ftp seem to be the way to go. I google some about the ftp transfer with c# code but honestly I did not find anything that is value to me, they are all to messy. u got any example on this?

Comment: @GrayWizardx: Note that SFTP (Secure Shell FTP) and FTP have nothing in common.  There are ways of securing the original FTP protocol, though, such as tunneling over SSL.

Comment: I agree completely but they are routinely referred to as the same thing (at least with the vendors/customers I deal with) as SFTP or FTP over SSL are cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did setup a ftp 7.5 on the iis7. Did a ftp transfer using the FtpWebRequest class. Homerun

looking into the sftp is the next step.

Answer (score 0):

**Darren Johnstone's File Upload control** is as good a solution as you will find anywhere.  It has the ability to handle large files without impacting the ASP.NET server memory, and can display file upload progress without requiring a Flash or Silverlight dependency.

http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/

Comment: I don't think he is looking for a file upload command.  I believe that he is looking to move the file from the web server over to the company server (which isn't running the web app).

Comment: Yea I was more on the server to server deal. but thx anyway Robert

Answer (score 0):

There isnt enough info to tell your whole hosting scenario but I have a few suggestions that might get you started in the right direction:

- Is your external server owned by another company or group and you cant modify it? If not you might consider hosting the process on the same machine, either in process or as a separate service on the machine. If it **cannot** be modified, you might consider hosting the service on the destination machine, that way its in the same place as the files need to show up at.
- Do the files need to stay in sync with the process? I.e. do they need to be uploaded, moved and verified as a single operation? If not then a separate process is probably the best way to go. The separate process will give you some flexibility, but remember it will be a separate process and a separate set of code to manage and work with
- How big is the file(s) that are being uploaded? Do they vary by upload? are the plain files, binaries (zips, executables, etc)? If the files are small you have more options than if they are large. If they are small enough, you can even relay them in line.

Depending on the answers to the above some of these might work for you:

- Use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx). This will work for simple messages under about 3MB without too much hassle. Its ideal for messages that can be directly worked with (such as XML).
- Use direct HTTP(s) relaying. On the host machine open a HTTP(s) connetion to the destination machine and transfer the file. Again this will work better for smaller files (i.e. only a few KB since it will be done in-line)
- If you have access to the host machine, deploy a separate process on the machine which builds or collects the files and uses any of the listed methods to send them to the destination machine.
- You can use SCP, FTP (of any form SFTP, etc) on either the host machine (if you have access) or the target machine to host the incoming files and use a batch process to move the files. This will have a lot of issues to address, such as file size, keeping submissions in sync, and timing. I would consider this as a last resort, depending on the situation.
- Again depending on message size, you could also use a layer of abstraction such as a DB to act as the intermediate layer between the two machines. This will work as long as the two machines can see the DB (or other storage location) and both act on it. [SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28SQL.90%29.aspx) could be used for this purpose (and most other DB products offer similar products).
- You can look at other products like [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/about/news/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-2/) or [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) to facilitate messaging between the two apps and do it inline.

Hopefully that will give you some starting points to look into.